# How to stop a timer counter at zero using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I have used the following code:

```
DispatcherTimer sec = new DispatcherTimer();
sec.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);

sec.Tick += delegate
{
     lblsec.Text = b--.ToString() + " Seconds.";
};

sec.Start();
c--;
```

this code will display a counter start from 5 and will decreases down and it will go negative.
my question is how to stop it when it reaches zero?

Comment: You called `sec.Stop` in `Tick`. Does that fires more than once?

Comment: ye it does. but I want it to start from 5 and stops at zero.

Comment: `if(b==0) sec.Stop();`?

Comment: Please consider either up-voting/accepting the answer for this question, _or explaining why that answer doesn't suit your needs_. There may be other similar questions in the future, and it would be helpful to have the question that's already been answered available to use for marking new questions as duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

First, your timer interval is way too short. You're never going to get single millisecond timer intervals from Windows, and for UI purposes the user is never going to perceive timer updates that quickly.  For something like this, 100ms or longer is much more appropriate.

Second, you cannot count on the timer being very precise. If you, for example, specify an interval of 100ms, you *might* get called back ten times in a second, but often you won't. It will depend on the resolution of the Windows thread scheduler as well as what other activities the UI thread is doing.

With that in mind, and with the assumption that what you are trying to do here is set a five-second timer and display the countdown to the user, something like this should work:

```
TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
{
    double secondsLeft = (total - sw.Elapsed).TotalSeconds;

    if (secondsLeft <= 0)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        secondsLeft = 0;
    }

    lblsec.Text = secondsLeft.ToString("0.0") + " Seconds";
};

sw.Start();
timer.Start();
```

**Addendum:**

Here is a complete WPF program illustrating how the above code might be used:

**C#:**

```
class TimerModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TimeSpan _timeLeft;
    private readonly ICommand _startCommand;

    public TimeSpan TimeLeft
    {
        get { return _timeLeft; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _timeLeft)
            {
                _timeLeft = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand Start { get { return _startCommand; } }

    public TimerModel()
    {
        _startCommand = new StartCommand(this);
    }

    private class StartCommand : ICommand
    {
        private bool _running;
        private readonly TimerModel _timerModel;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return !_running;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public StartCommand(TimerModel timerModel)
        {
            _timerModel = timerModel;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
            timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                TimeSpan timeLeft = total - sw.Elapsed;

                if (timeLeft <= TimeSpan.Zero)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    timeLeft = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    _running = false;
                    OnCanExecuteChanged();
                }

                _timerModel.TimeLeft = timeLeft;
            };

            sw.Start();
            timer.Start();
            _running = true;
            OnCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        private void OnCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO27333077CountdownTimer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO27333077CountdownTimer"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:TimerModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Start" Command="{Binding Start}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeLeft.TotalSeconds, StringFormat={}{0:0.0} Seconds}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Note that the time-keeping can also be done using the `DateTime.UtcNow` property instead of a `Stopwatch`. For example, you could change the `StartCommand.Execute()` method so that it looks like this instead:

```
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            DateTime finishTime = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
            timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                TimeSpan timeLeft = finishTime - DateTime.UtcNow;

                if (timeLeft <= TimeSpan.Zero)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    timeLeft = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    _running = false;
                    OnCanExecuteChanged();
                }

                _timerModel.TimeLeft = timeLeft;
            };

            timer.Start();
            _running = true;
            OnCanExecuteChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Do I need to add this code inside timer1_Tick() Event ?

Comment: @John: no, the code I showed would be added wherever you want to start the timer. There would be no need for a `timer1_Tick()` event handler method, because the code example itself already has that event handler, declared as an anonymous method subscribed directly to the event (i.e. `timer.Tick += (sender, e) => { ... };`). I have added a complete code example to better illustrate how the original code I posted could be used.